# How to change String Array to ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

Here is the original code which has defined String-Array (25). It is working perfectly. But I don't need to define it as 25.  Instead, I used arraylist. Please check my code.

Using String of array:

```
public String[] getemailAddr(String strAccountnbr) throws Exception {


        String strQuery2 = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        String[] emailAddress = new String[25];

        int i=0;

         strQuery2 =  "SELECT c.EmailAddress AS EmailAddress" +

            " FROM customeremailid c " +
            "WHERE c.AccountNbr = ? " ;

          logMsg("strQuery2: "+strQuery2);

          ps = getDBConn().prepareStatement(strQuery2);
          ps.setString(1, strAccountnbr);        
          rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {

                emailAddress[i]=(rs.getString("EmailAddress")); 
                logMsg("emailAddress[i]"+" "+i+": "+emailAddress[i]);   
                i=i+1;

            }

        return emailAddress;  
        }
```

Here, I need to change String-Array to Arraylist. I tried something like this,

```
public String[] getemailAddr(String strAccountnbr) throws Exception {


        String strQuery2 = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
       //Newly tried // 
        ArrayList<String> strArrEmailIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] emailAddress= new String[strArrEmailIds.size()];
        strArrEmailIds.toArray(emailAddress);
        //Newly tried // 
        int i=0;

         strQuery2 =  "SELECT c.EmailAddress AS EmailAddress" +

            " FROM customeremailid c " +
            "WHERE c.AccountNbr = ? " ;

          logMsg("strQuery2: "+strQuery2);

          ps = getDBConn().prepareStatement(strQuery2);
          ps.setString(1, strAccountnbr);        
          rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {

                emailAddress[i]=(rs.getString("EmailAddress")); 
                logMsg("emailAddress[i]"+" "+i+": "+emailAddress[i]);   
                i=i+1;

            }

        return emailAddress;  
        }
```

Email ids are get from database instead of example.com.

But I am getting
 `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` error
 in this line. 
`emailAddress[i]=(rs.getString("EmailAddress"));`

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

This is not how you use an `ArrayList`.

First, you need to write:

```
List<String> strArrEmailIds = new ArrayList<>();
```

So, program to the `interface` and use the Java 7 diamond operator.

Next, remove the index `i`. You don't need this.

Finally, just do:

```
emailAddress.add(rs.getString("EmailAddress"));
```

To convert it back to an `String[]` you can then do:

```
String[] arr = emailAddress.toArray(new String[emailAddress.size()]);
```

Here is my suggestion for you final code:

```
public String[] getemailAddr(String strAccountnbr) throws Exception {
    final List<String> emailAddress = new ArrayList<>();
    final String strQuery2 = "SELECT c.EmailAddress AS EmailAddress"
            + " FROM customeremailid c "
            + "WHERE c.AccountNbr = ? ";
    try (final PreparedStatement ps = getDBConn().prepareStatement(strQuery2)) {
        ps.setString(1, strAccountnbr);
        try (final ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                emailAddress.add(rs.getString("EmailAddress"));
            }
        }
    }
    return emailAddress.toArray(new String[emailAddress.size()]);
}
```

I have removed your pointless assignments to `null`. I have added try-with-resources blocks to **close your external resources**, you code was one massive memory leak.

Comment: i value is to iterate the result set to get the emailaddress from database. How can I remove it? Can you please answer it as full code

Comment: @user3152748 You are mistaken. Your `i` value is only used to index into the array you *have now removed*. It is not necessary with a list. You have been provided with enough info in this answer to solve the problem - just apply a little brain power to it.

Comment: Code is working as expected. But getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 and java.lang.NullPointerException error..

Comment: From _where_? You either update your question or post a new question with the stacktrace.

Comment: yours and 
Subhrajyoti Majumder code is working good..but geting the error :(

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `ArrayList`, then you dont need a array again, indeed a `ArrayList` is backed by `Array` itself and its dynamic in size.

```
List<String> emailAddress= new ArrayList<String>(); // dynamic array
...
while(rs.next()){
    emailAddress.add((rs.getString("EmailAddress"));
    ...
}
return emailAddress.toArray(new String[emailAddress.size()]); // creating array of String type
```

And `ArrayList#toArray` converts `List` to `Array` which has done at last in the code.

Comment: Getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2  error. :(

Comment: When it returns, I need the value to be as string of array. Please consider!

Comment: yes that is why `emailAddress.toArray(new String[emailAddress.size()])`, it converts your `ArrayList` to `Array` And remember no need of array into the method.

Comment: Code is working as expected. But getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 and java.lang.NullPointerException error..

Comment: It must somewhere else, if it is then post a new question with detail dude

Answer (score 0):

declare it as

```
ArrayList<String> emailAddress= new ArrayList<String>();
...
emailAddress.add((rs.getString("EmailAddress"));
```

convert it to String[]:

```
return emailAddress.toArray(new String[emailAddress.size()]);
```

Comment: AtLast I need to convert it to Array of String..I dont need the return value to be in ArrayList

Comment: You know the size, use it. Calling `new String[0]{}` causes the creation of two arrays - the empty one you pass in and one of the correct size. This is a little wasteful.

Comment: It's a so tiny consumption that can be ignroed.

Answer (score 0):

You use ArrayList here wrongly in your code. When you define

```
ArrayList<String> strArrEmailIds = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] emailAddress= new String[strArrEmailIds.size()];
strArrEmailIds.toArray(emailAddress);
```

`strArrEmailIds` by default has a size of 0, so the generated `emailAddress` array also gets a length of 0. Later in the while loop, you are trying to assign the value to the `emailAddress[0]`, it will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Instead, the correct way is :

```
ArrayList<String> strArrEmailIds = new ArrayList<String>();
//....
while(rs.next()){
    //....
    strArrEmailIds.add(rs.getString("EmailAddress"));
}
//....
String[] emailAddress = strArrEmailIds.toArray(new String[strArrEmailIds.size()]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 if your result set goes beyond 25 itteration.
```

**How to convert `array` to `ArrayList` ?**

```
Arrays.asList(myArray)
```

in your case you can have a `list` and in the `resulset` itteration you can add them to the list like

```
List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
while(...){
emails.add(rs.getString("EmailAddress"));
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList` is **of fixed size**. This doesn't change anything apart from access semantics.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Agree..OP has asked for how to convert so gave an option of asList...in the second paragraph has given the solution....

Comment: you mean I should have pointed like : new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(myArray)) this you mean?